# Does updating the value of a column in SQLite reprocess other columns in that row, making it more efficient to use multiple tables? (1 vs 2 tables)

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

This question is about how to achieve the best possible performance with SQLite.

If you have a table with one column that you update very often, and another column that you update very rarely, is it better to split up that table into 2 different tables, so that you have 2 tables with 1 column (excluding primary key) each, instead of 1 table with 2 columns (excluding primary key) each?

I have tried to find information about this in the SQLite Documentation, but I have no been able to find an explanation for what exactly happens on updating one column of one row of a table. The closest answer to my question I found was this:

> During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing, the complete content of each row in the database is encoded as a single BLOB. So the SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH parameter also determines the maximum number of bytes in a row.

(Quoted from here: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

To me that sounds as if every row is internally stored as one big blob of all columns, and that would mean that updating a single column of the row will indeed lead to the whole row being internally re-encoded again, including all other columns of that row, even if they have not been modified as part of the UPDATE. But I am not sure if I understand that sentence I quoted correctly.

I am thinking about a case where you have one column that stores some big blob with multiple MB of size, and another column that stores some integer. The column with the big blob might only be updated once a month, while the column with the integer might be updated once per second. As far as I currently understand it based on that quote, it seems that updating the integer once per second will lead to the multiple MB of blob to be re-encoded again every time you update the integer, and that would be very inefficient. Having one table for the blob, and a different table for the integer would be a lot better then.

Comment: In general in databases, an entire row is stored, not individual columns.  There are columnar databases, but I don't think SQLite operates that way.  So, updating one column involves changing the entire row.  However, rows are usually combined together on pages, so the overhead is on the page level, not the record level.

Comment: *During part of SQLite's INSERT and SELECT processing...* nothing is mentioned about an UPDATE.